# Past Simple or Present Perfect in a Subordinate Clause with 'Until'

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect, subordinate-clauses

> I waited until he found out the truth before I attempted to explain myself.

OR

> I waited until he had found out the truth before I attempted to explain myself.

Is Past Perfect necessary here? I think it's just a sequence of actions, but the subordinate clause is really confusing.

Comment: Both are valid, but the "had" is not necessary, and most people would leave it out. I think it would be more common to include the "had" in writing versus speech, because saying "he had" is awkward (and might be contracted to he'd anyway). But even in written text, it'd usually be left out. Note that in my previous sentence, I contracted "it would" to it'd. In that case, you do need to say "it would" or "it'd"; it would be ungrammatical to say "it be left out".

Answer (score 0):

> - (1) I waited until he found out the truth before I attempted to explain myself.
> - (2) I waited until he had found out the truth before I attempted to explain myself.

Example (2)uses the past prefect, and uses it correctly. It is appropriate here because the "finding out" occurred before the "explaining". But the past perfect construction is not required. Example (1) is also valid, and has the same meaning in this case, as [the comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/331278/past-simple-or-present-perfect-in-a-subordinate-clause-with-until#comment626795_331278) by max pleaner points out.

I am not sure which form is more frequently used in sentences similar to this. There are situations in which moving from the past perfect to the simple past changes the meaning significantly, but this is not one of them.

In simplified terms, this sentence simply means:

> I waited for X before I did Y.

the use of a subordinate clause is is merely a common way of expressing that sort of meaning. Does that help your confusion?